# Issue with .gitconfig file

Tags: bash, git, github, command-line-interface, git-bash

I am getting an error message when I try to run the command `git config --global user.name` into bash. The error message reads:

> error: could not lock config file C:/Projects/.gitconfig: No such file or directory

When I do `echo $HOME`, I get `/c/projects`

The folder `C:/Projects` doesn't even exist anymore  so I have some idea about what may be going on here. The PATH of an older version of GIT to reach the home directory was `c:/projects` and some wires may be getting crossed. Right

Well now... if this is the issue I don't know how to change the path back to `C:/users/anthonyd` (where the current `.gitconfig` file is located along with .bashrc, .gitignore. etc.) and until I do I can't run any commands without issue.

Of course I could be wrong about what's causing the issue, but if there is someone that recognizes this issue, or has had this problem before I would appreciate help with a fix.

Comment: If there is a `.gitconfig.lock` in that path, then delete it. Check the owner of the `.gitconfig` file, if it's not you then give yourself the ownership of the file

Answer (score 3):

You pointed out the root of the problem in the question.  The problem is with your `HOME` configuration.  Git is trying to open a file that doesn't exist, and the directory `HOME` is pointing to is non-existent too.  Change the path of your `HOME` environment variable to your actual home directory.

```
export HOME=/c/users/anthonyd
```

You can also add that export command to your `~/.bash_profile`.

Then, force the creation of the global configuration file with `git config --edit --global`.  This will give you the `.gitconfig` for editing global configurations in your new `HOME` directory.